# Reading input file in C

Tags: c, file-io

I need to read from an input file by using C programming language to do one of my assignments.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *input = readFromFile(argv);
    return 0;
}

char *readFromFile(char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    char *input, c;
    int i = 0;

    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        c = fgetc(fp);
        input[i++] = c;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return input;
}
```

I want to do this reading operation in another function, not in function `main()`. I tried, but couldn't do it.

When I try to do it with the code above, I get an error message that says:

> conflicting types for `readFromFile()`

How can I fix this error and do what I want?

Comment: You're dereferencing an uninitialized pointer (`input`)... This will crash.

Comment: `feof()` is plain wrong. Make sure you understand this. Don't put "C" on your CV until you do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong

Comment: Wood behind the mandate-arrow that in-flux with teaching the language, academia should be *required* to teach **debugging techniques**. This code never checks the result of `fopen()`, uses `feof()` incorrectly, writes through an uninitialized pointer into random memory, performs no boundary checking during reading, and utilizes assumed function-decl because there is no prototype before usage of `readFromFile()` in `main()`.

Comment: When I tried reading from the text file with the same code in main() function, it worked. So, I thought there were no mistakes in my code in readFromFile() function.

I'm gonna consider your answers, read and try to understand what you said about feof() function.

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare `readFromFile` before using it. The best way to do this is to add a prototype:

```
char *readFromFile(char *argv[]); /* note that the identifier is useless here */
```

**NB**: By the way, there is a lot of other errors in your source code. The main one is that you don't allocate memory for `input`. Therefore, you will try to dereference an unitialized pointer: this leads to an undefined behavior. Since you are returning your pointer, you need to use dynamic allocation.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
char *input = malloc(SIZE);
```

Moreover, your utilisation of `feof` is wrong.

Comment: There will be a lot of runtime error. However, when I add a prototype before `main` function, I personnally don't have compile error anymore.

Comment: Did you put the prototype above the `main` function?

Comment: When I declare it like you do and try to run the program, it stops working immediately.

Comment: So, there is no compilation error anymore. See my edit (and also the comments).

Comment: He is returning input, it must be on the heap or global.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: Right. Fixed (although could also be static storage duration).

Comment: How do you know that you' ll not overflow the buffer? You may newd some reallocation.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: Reallocation issues are rare in pratice. A good program coud also have a size's limit. The one thing you have to check is to check whether you don't go away from your buffer. A lot of input functions are designed like that.

Comment: Then protect the buffer and exit before overflowing the buffer, you can't take that risk.

Answer (score -2):

First of all you can choose between these:

**1.** Declare the function prototype;
 **2.** Declare the function before the main.

This way the function is recognized in main.To be fast I always declare function before the main.In readFromFile you aren't allocating the memory that you need, fixed it for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *readFromFile(char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    char *input, c;
    int i = 0;
    size_t size=100*sizeof(char);
    input=(char*)malloc(size);

    while( (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF )
    {
        if(++i == size)
        {
            size+= 100*sizeof(char);
            input=(char*)realloc(input,size);
        }
        input[i-1] = c;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return input;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *input = readFromFile(argv);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your reallocation strategy is not very efficient (BTW `sizeof(char)` and `malloc` cast are useless).

Comment: @Kirilenko My reallocation strategy is efficient speaking about CPU.You should know that realloc takes a lot of CPU, so instead of reallocating at every character, I allocate blocks of 100 Bytes.100 B are nothing in modern RAMs. About the cast, this is to silent the compiler warning, and sizeof(char) is because a char is not 1B on every machine.You should know this, every book taches this.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: You are wrong. 
1) An efficient reallocation should use geometric progression. (check here: http://www.bourguet.org/v2/cs/realloc/).  
2) The cast is useless in C, and it doesn't report any warning. You are maybe compiling with a C++ compiler.  
3) `sizeof(char)` is **always** 1. Not always 8 bits, however (rather `CHAR_BIT`). Buy an other book. ;-)

Comment: The reallocation strategy depends on what you have to the file, you can't say that the geometric progression is the best strategy.If you have blocks of 100 B on your file then that's the best strategy and btw I can't reach your french file.
However you were returning a memory allocated on the stack from a function, risking to overflow the buffer and having syntax error, then contest these details like casts (my compiler gives me a warning, then?) and efficiency.I think that this is simply ridicolous.